# Problema ao instanciar duas model em uma controller php

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo, framework, php-7

Fiz um mini framework, onde as Models extends de uma classe padrão que contem um crud, a única coisas que as models possui é a informação da tabela a ser usada. Porem quando tento utiliza duas models em um controller a primeira sobrescreve as informações da segunda.

Controller

```
namespace Controller;

use Helpers\Seguranca;
use Model\Login;
use Sistema\Controller as CI_controller;

class Usuario extends CI_controller
{

    // Models
    private static $ObjUsuario;
    private static $ObjLogin;


    // Método construtor
    function __construct()
    {
        // Executa o método parente
        parent::__construct();

        // Models
        self::$ObjUsuario = new \Model\Usuario(); // TABELA USUARIO
        self::$ObjLogin = new Login(); // TABALE LOGIN

        // AO TENTAR utilizar o usuario a tabela fica LOGIN

    } // END >> Fun::__construct()
}
```

MODEL USUARIO

```
namespace Model;

use Sistema\Database;


class Usuario extends Database
{
    private static $conexao;

    // Método construtor
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Carrega o construtor da class pai
        parent::__construct();

        // Retorna a conexao
        self::$conexao = parent::getConexao();

        // Seta o nome da tablea
        parent::setTable("usuario");

    } // END >> Fun::__construct()

} // END >> Class::Curso
```

MODEL LOGIN

```
namespace Model;

use Sistema\Database;


class Login extends Database
{
    private static $conexao;

    // Método construtor
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Carrega o construtor da class pai
        parent::__construct();

        // Retorna a conexao
        self::$conexao = parent::getConexao();

        // Seta o nome da tablea
        parent::setTable("login");

    } // END >> Fun::__construct()

} // END >> Class::Curso
```

CLASSE DATABASE

```
namespace Sistema;


use \PDO;

class Database
{
    private static $database;
    private static $db;

    private static $table;



    function __construct()
    {
        $database = null;

        // Configurações do Banco de dados
        require("./app/config/database.php");

        // Adiciona as configurações ao item privado
        self::$database = $database;

        try
        {
            // Realiza a conexão do banco
        }
        catch (\PDOException $e)
        {
            echo 'Error:'. $e->getMessage();
        }
    }





    // Método responsável por retornar a conexão
    // com o banco de dados
    public function getConexao()
    {
        return self::$db;
    }


    /**
     *  Métodos para facilitar o desenvolvimento de aplicações
     *  deixando um "CRUD" pré programado
     */


    // Seta a tabela
    public function setTable($table)
    {
        self::$table = $table;
    }

    //......//
}
```

Comment: Se você quer que cada classe mantenha uma referência ao nome da tabela, o campo `$table` não deveria ser `private static`.

Comment: Deveria colocar como? tinha colocado apenas private mas não conseguia utilizar ela nas outras funções

Comment: Você sabe o que os modificadores `private` e `static` fazem - principalmente quando utilizadas com herança?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava no tipo do campo $table. Estava setando ele como static alterei para private e funcionou.

- Anderson Carlos Woss que me ajudou com essa questão